# Generates random numbers with 11 digits

Tags: awk, sed, numeric-data

I need a command that generates random numbers with 11 digits.  How can this be done?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194882/how-to-generate-random-number-in-bash/1195035

Comment: are you doing this to generate a random but unique id number?  if so, why not just use `uuid` (which is 36 chars, not 11 - which should be fine if uniqueness is what's important)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
od -An  -N8 -d /dev/random | sed -e 's| ||g' -e 's|\(.\{11\}\).*|\1|'
```

Comment: Use `/dev/urandom` instead of `/dev/random` otherwise you'll likely end up blocking on the read.

Answer (score 7):

Run this from your terminal to get a random 11-digit number generated each time:

```
$ tr -cd '[:digit:]' < /dev/urandom | fold -w 11 | head -n 1
```

Comment: Deleting all those bytes is an extreme waste.

Answer (score 3):

With `shuf` from GNU coreutils:

```
shuf -n1 -i0-99999999999
```

Increase the value of the `-n` option if you need more than one number.